# SQL Comparar valores em outras linhas

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenho uma tabela chamada `transferencia` que possui dados sobre a movimentação de um hospede em um hotel, por exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela não possui data da saída, logo a data da saída é a `data_entrada` em que a `transferencia` é igual a `transferencia + 1`.

Eu preciso fazer uma consulta que retorne uma coluna a mais com a data da saída descrito no paragrafo acima e caso a ultima `transferencia` seja igual a `null`, deve retornar a quantidade de dias atual, considerando a data atual da consulta(no caso hoje, isso por que o hospede ainda está hospedado). Caso o valor do ultimo registro de `transferencia` seja <> `null`, é por que o hospede já foi embora e o sistema calculou a quantidade de dias que ele ficou hospedado.

Meu SGBD é o Firebird 2.5

Comment: Não entendi sua explicação afinal matematicamente x nunca é igual a x+1. Em seu exemplo a data de saída é 07/01/2019 ou 08/01/2019? Para os dados apresentados tente colocar qual o resultado esperado.

Comment: Por que a data de saída tem que ser o próximo registro, e não a data_entrada mas a coluna qtde_dias?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma `subquery` para buscar o próximo registro. Dessa forma também não há perigo de quebrar a lógica se houver um "buraco" nos sequenciais:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT FIRST 1 t2.data_entrada
          FROM tranferencia t2
         WHERE t2.codigo_hospede = t.codigo_hospede
           AND t2.transferencia > t.transferencia
         ORDER BY t2.transferencia) AS data_saida
  FROM transferencia t
```

Comment: Obrigado Sorack, eu script foi de grande ajuda

Comment: @RafaelChristófano se a resposta lhe atendeu não esqueça de marca lá como escolhida

Comment: adicionei a sua reposta o calculo para contar a quantidade de dias caso o hospede continue hospedado.

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo a minha própria pergunta, com a ajudar do Sorack, mais incrementando a questão de contar os dias caso o hospede continue hospedado.

```
select transf.codigo_hospede, transf.transferencia, transf.data_entrada, transf.quarto, 
iif(transf.qtde_dias is null,  DATEDIFF(day, transf.data_entrada, current_date),transf.qtde_dias),
from (
       SELECT t.*,
           (SELECT FIRST 1 t2.data_entrada
             FROM tranferencia t2
             WHERE t2.codigo_hospede = t.codigo_hospede
             AND t2.transferencia > t.transferencia
             ORDER BY t2.transferencia) AS data_saida
        FROM transferencia t) as transf
```